# How to update JLabel in Swing?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, timer

I am trying to use Swing Timer and I wanted to start from a very simple program. I have a window with text: "You have n seconds", where n changes from 10 to 0 every second.

I know how to generate a window with text. And I understand how Timer works (it starts an action periodically). But I cannot figure out how to combing this two things. Should I use that: `JLabel label = new JLabel(myMessage);` and then with timer I need to update the "myMessage" variable?

But I think I need to "force" my window to "update" itself (to display a new value stored in "myMessage").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to call the `JLabel#setText` method each time content is updated. however, due to the very monothread nature of Swing, you have to update its widgets in the so-called Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). To do so, consider calling `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` or `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` in your timer code.

This way, when text will be changed due to your call of setText, events of JLabel will propagate correctly, and label will be correctly refreshed.

Comment: -1/2 :), using setText() is basic, so its not really worth +1 and all Timer code does execute on the EDT so it is not necessary to use invokeLater().

Comment: It depends upon the timer you use. If you use the javax.swing.Timer, indeed code is run in the EDT. however, in the most general case, people tend to use java.util.Timer which won't run in EDT, then require the EDT synchronization code, which is indeed the hardest part to understand.

Answer (score 5):

Hi bro  use  observer pattern . That is ,your ui class  sould be listener of  your timer structure.When your variable changes ,invoke the listeners of your timer which is your ui class.

```
//your observer class 

update(Object obj){

label.setText(obj.toString());
}
...

//your observable class
//when timer changes varible's value  you should call invokeListeners() 


invokeListener(){

for(Listener listener :listeners)
listener.update(getSecond());
}
```

I dont know your class and structure.But i used this solution in one of my assignments.